# Realm - Get a list of all parents of all children from the child point of view

Tags: swift, realm, parent-child, predicate

In a game I am writing using Realm and Swift I'm trying to do this relationship;

`Locomotive -> Engine <- Player`

- A `Player` has many `Engines`
- A `Locomotive` has many `Engines`

As a sidenote, A player can only ever own one engine (child) from one locomotive (parent).

I'm wanting to get a list of all parents of all children that a player owns using Realm and NSPredicates.

That is to say, given a player entity; list all parents of all the engines that a player owns and sort the parent objects by cost.

As the app doesn't know directly which player owns what locomotive, I'd like to do a query on the engines that a player owns to find out what locomotive they own.

I feel its a bit overkill to have 2 relationships in the locomotive entity (one for all the engines, and one for all the players) when that information can be garned through its child object(s).

Specifically, I want a list of all locomotives that a player owns, sorted by cost through the engines entity.  (I hope this makes sense)

The relevant code from my project is as follows;

```
// Locomotive entity

public class Locomotive: Object {
   var engines = List<Engine>()
   private(set) dynamic var cost: Int = 0
}

// Engine entity

public class Engine: Object {
    private let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Locomotive.self, property: "engines")
    private let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Player.self, property: "engines")

}

// Player entity

public class Player: Object {
    public let engines = List<Engine>()
}

    // Give me a list of all locomotives I own through the engines entity
// and sort the locomotives by cost

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY engines.owners == %@", firstPlayer)

        let allLocos = realm.objects(Player.self)
            .filter(predicate)

        print (allLocos.count)
```

Whilst this gives me a list of all engines where the player owns, it doesn't give me the list of locomotives (or sorted by cost)

Thus my query is:

How do I grab a list of all parents (locomotives) from all children that the player owns and ensure that the sort order is by cost?

I am hopeful that I have explained my issue correctly and welcome any help and assistance that may result from my query.

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, I am able to get the list from the locomotive side, but I'm after it from the player side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read that right, given a `Player` object, you want to retrieve a list of the `Locomotive` objects that are the parents of the `Engine` objects that are children of that `Player` object.

You should be able to do a lookup against the `Locomotive` object using the `Player` object's `engines` property. It would look something like this (Although admittedly, this is untested):

```
let player = // Get the player
let locomotives = realm.objects(Locomotive.self).filter("ANY self IN %@", player.engines)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I am currently doing it (well a version of it).  I was attempting to see if I could go the reverse way -- but it proved a bit more difficult.   Regardless; I'm going to accept your answer

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Wait, the reverse way? So, as in taking a single `Locomotive` and working out any `Player` objects that might share `Engine` objects with it?

Comment: Ignore me, I was confusing myself.  As mentioned in query. I wanted `given a player entity; list all parents of all the engines that a player owns and sort the parent objects by cost.`  I believe your answer does solve this issue